# mysql query takes too long

Tags: mysql, sql

im working on a project and I created this sql query but it seems to be taking too long if I select a bigger date range, any idea how to make it faster, I tryed with `union all` and its much faster, but data is not the same, need help with code:

```
SELECT SUM(ROUND(total, 2)) as Enero from (
    SELECT 
    FORMAT (
    COALESCE(
    CONCAT(ROUND(pro.precio / 1.14 , 2) + ROUND(p.recargo / 1.14 , 2) + (SELECT SUM(ROUND(precio / 1.14 , 2)) AS precio FROM acompanante_orden WHERE id_orden=p.id_orden) - p.descuento),
    CONCAT(ROUND(pro.precio / 1.14 , 2) + ROUND(p.recargo / 1.14 , 2) - p.descuento) 
    )+ COALESCE(

    ROUND(CONCAT(ROUND(pro.precio / 1.14 , 2) + (SELECT SUM(ROUND(precio / 1.14 , 2)) AS precio FROM acompanante_orden WHERE id_orden=p.id_orden) + ROUND(p.recargo / 1.14 , 2) - p.descuento) * 0.14, 2), 
    ROUND(CONCAT(ROUND(pro.precio / 1.14 , 2) + ROUND(p.recargo / 1.14 , 2) - p.descuento) * 0.14, 2)
    ), 2) as total


    FROM orden p
    LEFT JOIN producto_orden AS pro ON p.id_orden = pro.id_orden
    LEFT JOIN acompanante_orden AS pa ON p.id_orden = pa.id_orden

    WHERE p.actual_date BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-01' and p.status=4 
) sum_1
```

UNION ALL IDEA

```
select ROUND(( sum(precio)) * 1.14,2) as total from (
    SELECT a.id_orden, ROUND(b.precio / 1.14 , 2) + ROUND(a.recargo / 1.14 , 2) - a.descuento as precio FROM orden a, producto_orden b WHERE a.id_orden=b.id_orden and a.actual_date BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-01' and a.status=4 union all
    SELECT c.id_orden, ROUND(d.precio / 1.14 , 2) as precio FROM orden c, acompanante_orden d WHERE c.id_orden=d.id_orden and c.actual_date BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-01' and c.status=4
) sum_1
```

**UPDATE:**

SO here is my table schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fe12/2

**WHAT I NEED:**

I need to get TOTAL of monthly SELLS, but values on DB are with TAXES so before I get total I need to do some math:

**DB INFO**

```
PRODUCT= $50.00
ADDONS= $8.00
SHIPPING= $6.00

DISCOUNT= $2.00
```

**RESULTS I NEED:**

```
PRODUCT= $50.00 / 1.14 = $43.86
ADDONS= $8.00 / 1.14 = $7.02
SHIPPING= $6.00 / 1.14 =$5.26

SUBTOTAL= $56.14 - DISCOUNT($2)= $54.14

SUBTOTAL= $54.14 * 1.14 = $61.72
```

Comment: What does EXPLAIN tell you? What indexes do you have on the tables involved? How long is *too long*? When you're doing a subselect on every column in every single row, plus multiple function calls, how do you expect to get any decent performance in your query?

Comment: EXPLAIN: http://imgur.com/a/aQS72
INDEXES: NONE
LONG dependes on the date range if I select '2017-02-01' AND '2017-04-01' it takes around 6 sec in UNION ALL 1 sec....and yes I know it makes a lot of functions, thats why Im asking if there's a better way to achive results.

Comment: It's difficult to tell you whether there's a better way or not, because you've not included your table schemas, sample data, and the output you expect to get from that data. The schemas should be in the form of CREATE TABLE DDL so someone can create the tables if they'd like in order to work out an answer.

Comment: ok, i understand let me create schemas and update post

Comment: Tip: the best way to do that is to run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table name, and copy & paste the text, instead of doing screen shots.

Comment: I notice that you have the same correlated subqueries in multiple places. It would probably be better to do that as a subquery using `GROUP BY id_orden ` that you `JOIN` with the main query.

Comment: The EXPLAIN shows that you're not using any idexes. Make sure you have an index on the `actual_date` field and any fields that are used in the `ON` conditions.

Comment: @KenWhite does this work? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fe12/2

Comment: What is `UNION ALL IDEA`?

Comment: I added update to question, please check

Comment: should I drop all INDEXES I created after sql query is done?

Answer (score 1):

The first subquery is basically:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM orden p LEFT JOIN
     producto_orden pro
     ON p.id_orden = pro.id_orden LEFT JOIN
     acompanante_orden pa
     ON p.id_orden = pa.id_orden
WHERE p.actual_date BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-01' and
      p.status = 4
```

For this query, you want indexes on `orden(status, actual_date, id_id_orden)`, producto_orden(id_orden)`, and`acompanante_orden(id_orden)`.

I'm not sure what the rest of the query is.

Comment: should I drop all INDEXES I created after sql query is done?

Comment: @Ered . . . That seems like a bad idea.  You might want to run a similar query in the future.

Comment: ok so I just leave the index to those rows, BTW could u take a look on the UPDATE on my post to see if theres a better query to what I need?